# CI Pass the received variables array in a view to another view

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I am currently loading my header, footer and content views from the controller like this:

```
$data = array('first' => 1, 'second' => 2);
$this->load->view('header', $data);
$this->load->view('CRUD/reports', $data);
$this->load->view('footer', $data);
```

How can I pass the "`$data`" array to header and footer from the "CRUD/reports" view so I can just load the main content view from the controller like this:

```
$this->load->view('CRUD/reports', $data);
```

Comment: Can you explain why the downvote?

Comment: Where is $this->data defined? It needs to be either an array or object to pass to the view.

Comment: Edited the question based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the variable `$_ci_vars` which is available to the CRUD/reports view in my scenario. Then loading the header and footer from that view like this:

```
$this->load->view('header', $_ci_vars);
$this->load->view('header', $_ci_vars);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can allways load the header and footer in the view file or you can make a function like :

```
function get_header($data, $return = false, $view = "header") {
    $ci = & get_instance();
    $ci->load->view($view, $data, $return);
}
```

And then in your data make a **$data->header** values and pass them to the function in the view file like :

```
// View file
<?php get_header($header);?>
// Other content of the file
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading the header and footer in your controller, you can load it in the your "CRUD/reports" view, use

```
$this->load->view('header');
//Your "CRUD/reports" content
$this->load->view('footer');
```

You can send all your variable in the "data" array as follows

```
$this->data['variable1'] = 'values';
$this->data['variable2'] = 'values';
```

Then load the view as follows

```
$this->load->view('CRUD/reports', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

At now I'm using [PARSER](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/parser.html)

#### Controller

```
<?php
    $template = array(
        'title'=>'My invoices',
        'headerinc'=>load_css('data-tables/DT_bootstrap', 'plugins'),
        'footerinc'=>load_js('jquery.dataTables', 'plugins'), FALSE),
        'content'=>$CI->load->view("invoice/visualize", $data, TRUE)
    );
    
    $CI->parser->parse($CI->load->view['template'], $template); 
?>
```

**Main view** (view template.php)

```
<html>
    <head>
        {headerinc}
    </head>
    <body>
        {content}

        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

        {footerinc}
    </body>
</html>
```

In this form your website always will stay with the same style changing only the content =)